# How to fix Unexpected token { when running npx cypress?

Tags: cypress

I run

```
npx cypress
```

And get

Unexpected token {

Maybe there is a way to get more details, tried:

```
DEBUG=cypress:server:socket-base npx cypress
```

But still same error and no more info. First it was working, I think I did not change anything and one day it started giving this error. Maybe I changed something not knowing that I did.

Maybe it has to do something with versions?

```
npx -v
6.14.5
```

**Update:**

Executed different way

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/cypress 
/home/darius/Private/Projects/vop-live-automated-checks/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/darius/Private/Projects/vop-live-automated-checks/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
```

Maybe this is same but full error?

Comment: Can you post your entire error message?

Comment: @AlapanDas - how can I get entire error message ? :) at least in console I only get  this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just deleted node_modules and ran

```
npm install
```

and now works.

Answer (score 0):

If it suddenly happened, you might have switched out of bash terminal. double check.